# Knockout JS array empty or can't retrieve values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a Javascript ajax function that retrieves comments from the server(Note: I'm new to Knockout JS):

```
function Comments() {
var self = this;
self.commentArray = ko.observableArray();
self.getNewerComments = function(lastCommentId) {
    pageId = $('body').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Controller/getNewerComments/" + pageId + "/" + lastCommentId,


    })
            .done(function(data) {

                self.commentArray = ko.observableArray(data);
                alert(self.commentArray[0].authorName);


            })

}

}
```

With the alert I can see that the value is indeed set there, at the start of my JS file I have the following code:

```
var comments = new Comments();
ko.applyBindings(comments);
comments.getNewerComments(0);
```

And in the html file:

```
<!-- ko foreach: commentArray -->
<li>Item <span data-bind="text: $index"></span></li>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

However, nothing shows up in the html document, not even the "Item" text, which indicates the array has 0 length. 
**What's the problem here? Why can't I use the array values?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use existing observable array (which was bound) instead of creating a new one:

```
.done(function(data) {
   self.commentArray(data);
   alert(self.commentArray[0].authorName);
 })
```

Comment: Oh nvm misread, it was upvote that I couldn't do until I had 15 rep. Marked as answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the observable array twice.  At the start and again at the Ajax call.  Once you have the model built and apply bindings, no need to mess with observables again.  It's done. Any changes to your data object tied to the model will be handled.