# requirejs w/ knockoutjs w/ select2 fails to update observable on first load

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, jquery-select2, amd

The first time that we load the requirejs module the observables from my view model seems not to being updated. But when you comment `$("#ddl").select2();` everything works fine.

```
requirejs.config({
    'paths': {
        'jquery': '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min',
            'ko': '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0',
            'select2': '//ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.5/select2',
            'domReady': 
                '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady/2.0.1/domReady'
    },
        'shim': {
        'select2': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$.select2'
        }
    }
});

define('simpleKo', ['jquery', 'ko', 'domReady', 'select2'],

function ($, ko, domReady) {
    var simpleViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable();
        self.names = ko.observableArray(['John', 'Tim', 'Mike', 'Jay']);
    };

    domReady(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new simpleViewModel());
        $("#ddl").select2({
            width: 'resolve'
        });
    });
});

requirejs(['simpleKo']);
```

There is a live exemple on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rubenslopes/kffq6cjb/) that fails when you first open the link without cache.

I've already tried everything, anyone have ideas to what may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way is tell to RequireJS that KnockoutJS depends of select2, even though it's not truth.

```
        'shim': {
            'select2': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: '$.select2'
            },
            'ko' : {
                deps: ['select2']
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use custom binding handler for select2 (in the bootstrap environment):

```
<div data-bind="selectbox: { value: selectedValueId, values: values || [{id: 1, text: 'text'}], lookupId: 'id', lookupText: 'text', mode: 'id' }"/>
```

In spite of it may seems too complex, I post custom binding code here:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers["selectbox"] = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var nullValue = ["Unselected"];

            var options = valueAccessor(), value = options.value, values = (ko.unwrap(options.values) || []).map(function (item) {
                return { id: ko.unwrap(item[options.lookupId || "id"]), text: ko.unwrap(item[options.lookupText || "text"]) || "(undelected)" };
            }), getId = (function (object) {
                return object.id;
            }), findValue = options.findValue || (function (id) {
                //console.log(id, values.filter((object) => { console.log(getId(object)); return getId(object) == id; }));
                return values.filter(function (object) {
                    return (getId(object) == id) || (id == '' && getId(object) == null);
                })[0];
            }), initialValue = (options.mode === "id" ? findValue(ko.unwrap(value)) : ko.unwrap(value)) || { text: "(undefined)" };

            //console.log(value());
            var $selectContainerTemplate = $("<div class='input-group' />");
            var $selectTemplate = $("<input type='hidden' style='width: 100%;' />");
            $selectContainerTemplate.append($selectTemplate);

            values = [{ id: null, text: "(undefined)" }].concat(values);

            $(element).children().remove();
            $(element).append($selectTemplate);
            $selectTemplate["select2"]({
                initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                    callback(ko.unwrap(initialValue));
                },
                data: values,
                id: getId
            });
            $selectTemplate.change(function (event) {
                //alert(event.val);
                var newValue = findValue(event["val"]);
                if (options.mode === "id") {
                    newValue = newValue["id"];
                }
                if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                    value(newValue);
                } else {
                    value = newValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Are we talking about the same plugin over here? [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Defenitely. The initializaion code is "$selectTemplate["select2"]({ ... some options ... });", where "$selectTemplate" is a jquery wrapper. As an items list I use an array of [{id: 1, text: 'text'}] objects. My case is a lookup for a linked object.

Comment: I manage to make it work partially, it still does not select the correct initial value. Working on it...

Comment: in options "selectbox: { value: selectedValueId ..." - "selectedValueId" is a name of a field in the model, which is used as initial value and as a field where selected value will be stored after selection has been changed

Comment: Sure it is, but i think the problem is in the ajax that brings that data from the server. The select2 is bound before selectedValueId get any actual value. And even when it finishes the request the select2 don't assume the correct value, but if I set manually, ex: svm.selectedId(5), the change event is triggered

Comment: Are you sure that you do not recreate your model on ajax completed? Similar problem was discussed in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527529/knockout-js-array-empty-or-cant-retrieve-values/26527610#26527610 thread.