# How to use knockout foreach binding with new data?

Tags: javascript, json, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a web page that fetches json data from the server with an ajax request like this:

```
function loadData() {
    doughnutData = [];
    $.getJSON('/Report/GetConsumption?StationId=' + Station + '&DataPointId=20507&StartTime=' + StartTime.toISOString() + '&EndTime=' + EndTime.toISOString() + '&IntervalSizeStr=' + IntervalSize, function (data) {
        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        viewModel.getColorForValue = function (val) {
            value = val / viewModel.MaxGridValue();
            var hue = ((1 - value) * 120).toString(10);
            if (value == 0) return ["rgb(70,70,70)"].join("");
            return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,50%)"].join("");
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('data'));

        for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Rows().length; i++) {
            doughnutData.push({
                value: viewModel.Rows()[i].ConsumptionTotal().toFixed(2),
                label: viewModel.Rows()[i].RowName()
            });
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, { responsive: true });
    });
}
```

This is the HTML part that actually displays the data:

```
    <div id="data">
        <div id="GridRow" data-bind="foreach: Rows">
            <div>
                <div data-bind="text: RowName()"></div>
                <div data-bind="text:(ConsumptionTotal()!=null?ConsumptionTotal().toFixed(2):ConsumptionTotal()) + ' kWh'" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;float:right;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <div data-bind="foreach: Values" style="clear:both;">
                    <div class="HeatGridCell" data-bind="attr: { title: (new Date(IntervalStart())).toLocaleString() + ': ' + (Value()!=null?Value().toFixed(2):Value()).toLocaleString() + 'kWh' } ,
                      style: {
                          backgroundColor: $root.getColorForValue(Value()),
                          border: '1px solid ' + $root.getColorForValue(Value()),
                          width: ''+((958/$parent.Values().length)-2) +'px',
                          height: '18px',
                          float: 'left'
                      }">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is some sample Json data for my viewModel:

```
{  
   "Text":"Energiebetrachtung für Station 2:",
   "Rows":[  
      {  
         "RowName":"Energieverbrauch",
         "StationId":9,
         "DataPointId":20507,
         "ConsumptionTotal":16531.0002,
         "Values":[  
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420119961659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420206361659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420292761659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420379161659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420465561659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420551961659,
               "Value":0
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420638361659,
               "Value":16.419
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420724761659,
               "Value":33.7859
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420811161659,
               "Value":1.0555
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420897561659,
               "Value":55.0716
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1420983961659,
               "Value":1.5794
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421070361659,
               "Value":1.5794
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421156761659,
               "Value":1.5794
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421243161659,
               "Value":1.5794
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421329561659,
               "Value":13.7923
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421415961659,
               "Value":380.2002
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421502361659,
               "Value":304.2716
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421588761659,
               "Value":348.5954
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421675161659,
               "Value":512.8432
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421761561659,
               "Value":926.8025
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421847961659,
               "Value":915.4359
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1421934361659,
               "Value":959.0111
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422020761659,
               "Value":944.8331
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422107161659,
               "Value":849.0834
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422193561659,
               "Value":324.6436
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422279961659,
               "Value":88.0598
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422366361659,
               "Value":1.3593
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422452761659,
               "Value":232.3545
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422539161659,
               "Value":586.8022
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422625561659,
               "Value":524.1148
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422711961659,
               "Value":378.3096
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422798361659,
               "Value":693.6768
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422884761659,
               "Value":656.1949
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1422971161659,
               "Value":1037.8794
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423057561659,
               "Value":1241.6998
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423143961659,
               "Value":1176.4226
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423230361659,
               "Value":1141.9589
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423316761659,
               "Value":29.8893
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423403161659,
               "Value":44.1929
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423489561659,
               "Value":6.4767
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423575961659,
               "Value":10.1638
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423662361659,
               "Value":319.7191
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423748761659,
               "Value":178.564
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423835161659,
               "Value":3.3811
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1423921561659,
               "Value":78.1026
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424007961659,
               "Value":284.9436
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424094361659,
               "Value":122.8865
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424180761659,
               "Value":310.0112
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424267161659,
               "Value":117.0268
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424353561659,
               "Value":11.1318
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424439961659,
               "Value":3.0199
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424526361659,
               "Value":91.8154
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424612761659,
               "Value":143.7019
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424699161659,
               "Value":122.9965
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424785561659,
               "Value":88.1888
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424871961659,
               "Value":0.7581
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1424958361659,
               "Value":0.7581
            },
            {  
               "IntervalStart":1425044761659,
               "Value":212.2776
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "StartDate":1420119961659,
   "EndDate":1425131167601,
   "MinGridValue":0,
   "MaxGridValue":1241.6998
}
```

Here's my problem: I want to change some variables like the `StationId` or `StartTime`, `EndTime` and then pull the new data from the server by calling `loadData()`. This part works and the data is received, but the UI gets messed up completely, probably because the structure of the viewModel is quite variable with different numbers of rows and different amounts of values within each row.

So what I need is some kind of UI *reset*, so to speak. In other words: when the new data arrives, the UI should be set to the same state that it is in when the page initially gets loaded. After that, the `ko.mapping` and `ko.applyBindings` can be called.

I could of course DO a page reload, but I really want to avoid that. What would be the best approach to resolve this issue? Thanks alot!

Comment: Hmm it ought to just work due to data binding but what if you try to do `if (viewModel && viewModel.Rows){ viewModel.Rows.removeAll(); }` before `ko.mapping.fromJS(data);`. That way you ensure that the view is cleared before assigning new data.

Comment: You needn't reload page and execute ko.applyBindings() again if you will use one (e.g.) global observable variable and update it's content on data loaded. You can check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221094/knockout-js-new-data-source-refresh-html/28222176#28222176 thread here.

Answer (score 0):

You should break the code in the two separate part.

1. The view initialization, where you setup view model object, and bind it using `ko.applyBinding`
2. The part where you update your view model based on data from the server.

```js
var viewModel;

// View should be setup one time for the application.
// No need the recreate view model each time when you load data 
// from the server. It is actually would be performance hit.
function setupView() {
    viewModel = {
      data: ko.observable(),
      getColorForValue: function (val) {
        value = val / viewModel.MaxGridValue();
        var hue = ((1 - value) * 120).toString(10);
        if (value == 0) return ["rgb(70,70,70)"].join("");
        return ["hsl(", hue, ",100%,50%)"].join("");
      },

      // Here the power of KO. Computed properties.
      // Use with caution.
      // This property will be recalculated when you data would be changed.
      // See function below for usage.
      doughnutData: ko.computed(function () {
          var doughnutData = [];
          var rows = viewModel.data().Rows();
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            doughnutData.push({
                value: rows[i].ConsumptionTotal().toFixed(2),
                label: rows[i].RowName()
            });
          }
          return doughnutData;
      }, this);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('data'));
}

// This function now could be called multiple times.
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON('/Report/GetConsumption?StationId=' + Station + '&DataPointId=20507&StartTime=' + StartTime.toISOString() + '&EndTime=' + EndTime.toISOString() + '&IntervalSizeStr=' + IntervalSize, function (data) {
        
        // HERE THE UPDATE OF THE VIEW.
        // The trick is to create special property which will hold the data.
        viewModel.data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

        // True power of Knockout comes from the computed properties and bindings
        // Below example of using computed properties.
        var doughnutData = viewModel.doughnutData();

        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, { responsive: true });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <div id="data" data-bind="with: data">
        <div id="GridRow" data-bind="foreach: Rows">
            <div>
                <div data-bind="text: RowName()"></div>
                <div data-bind="text:(ConsumptionTotal()!=null?ConsumptionTotal().toFixed(2):ConsumptionTotal()) + ' kWh'" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;float:right;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <div data-bind="foreach: Values" style="clear:both;">
                    <div class="HeatGridCell" data-bind="attr: { title: (new Date(IntervalStart())).toLocaleString() + ': ' + (Value()!=null?Value().toFixed(2):Value()).toLocaleString() + 'kWh' } ,
                      style: {
                          backgroundColor: $root.getColorForValue(Value()),
                          border: '1px solid ' + $root.getColorForValue(Value()),
                          width: ''+((958/$parent.Values().length)-2) +'px',
                          height: '18px',
                          float: 'left'
                      }">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```